# Troubles with persisting relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I ran into a problem when I'm trying to persist User entity with its relations:

```
class User {

        /**
         * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserDataAttribute", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        private $customAttributes;
}

class UserDataAttribute
{
        /**
         * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="customAttributes")
         * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $user;
}
```

When I specify @JoinColumn as `name="user_id"` in database goes this query:

```
INSERT INTO user_data_attr (user_id) VALUES (null);
```

And when I specify @JoinColumn as `name="userId"` in database goes this query:

```
 INSERT INTO user_data_attr (userId) VALUES (2323 (the actual value)));
```

But what I need is:

```
INSERT INTO user_data_attr (user_id) VALUES (2323);
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: you shouldn't need to define the join column at all if you can live with the default here

Comment: I am not sure what you meant

Comment: see the provided answer - that is what i meant - accept the answer when it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserDataAttribute", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $customAttributes;


     /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="customAttributes")
     */
    private $user;
```

And check it before:
`app/console doctrine:schema:validate` for Symfony 2

```
                `app/console doctrine:schema:valid` for Symfony 3
```